# How to prevent <a> to go to a link?

Tags: jquery

How can I display a yes/no prompt when a user clicks a certain `<a>` with an id='yes' and then if he clicks yes I proceed normally if no nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers! I have another question. Does preventDefault() permanently disable this action? I would like that if the user clicks the same link again and press yes, that the link would execute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#yes').click(function (e) { 
  if (!confirm('Message')) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#yes').click(function() {
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```

This will do nothing if they do not hit OK on the confirmation box that pops up, otherwise it goes to the link. You can change `#yes` to different things to cover more tags, I personally have `class="confirm"` on all links I want the end user to confirm (so `$('.confirm')` as selector).

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` with `e` being the first argument of the callback function is the proper way. For example, it also works if your callback function throws an exception somewhere and thus your `return false;` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yes').click(function(e) { 
   if (!confirm("are you sure?")) { 
      e.preventDefault(); 
   } 
});
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/gGB7u/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a different dialog box, like a LightBox or something you could use:

```
$("#yes").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    <call method show whatever dialog box you want to use>
});
```